# How to make a service/ function to expose on socket interface in Azure

Tags: azure, sockets, azure-api-management, azure-application-gateway

I have a use case where a mobile app wants to connect to my service and send an audio stream. The mobile end wanted to do this over a web socket. I am looking for possible ways to expose my service to the socket interface in Azure.

I thought of having an application gateway and landing it on Azure function but as I understood Azure Application Gateway is suitable for web traffic load balancing it cannot be configured to manage the socket connection.

This is a bit different I found in Azure, In AWS  there is a possibility to have api gateway and it could be of type HTTP or socket. If we select socket type it gives the connection URL to connect with.

How can I achieve this in Azure? What would be the better way to expose a service as a socket interface with load balancing + failover + security in place?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Application Gateway does support web socket:

> Application Gateway provides native support for WebSocket across all
> gateway sizes. There is no user-configurable setting to selectively
> enable or disable WebSocket support.

source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-websocket

then you can route traffic to Azure Web App or Azure Functions. There's also the possibility of using Azure SignalR + Azure Functions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-azure-functions-csharp?tabs=in-process

Comment: The Application Gateway does the connection management as well? Or it just route the request to the target application and we need to manage websocket connection in our Web App/ Azure Function.

Comment: it's possible with cookie affinity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-cookie-affinity?source=recommendations

Comment: By connection management I meant the backend application needs to run as a server and manage the connection, application gateway will just route the traffic to the backend? Gateway does not do the connection management. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-websocket

Comment: yes, the gateway will just forward the request